# Is possible to introduce the concept of weight of an answer/question?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation, voting

I suppose that an answer about C# voted by Eric Lippert and Jon Skeet is more endorsed (and maybe should be taken more into account) that another one voted by 2 random developers.

I think it will be useful for the developer to have access to a level of endorsement (value, weight) of any answer or question on Stack Overflow.

**Note that I am not talking about to know who is voting each question/answer.**

I am talking just about a number (maybe normalized) that shows of the level of endorsement of a question/answer (for example, maybe this number could be the sum of the reputations of the voters of the question/answer in that particular topic).

With that information the developer could suspect about some smells around some answers, for example: can see a question with 80 votes and a weight of 900000 with an answer of 80 votes, but a weight of just 100.

Comment: Note that Eric Lippert only upvotes by accident.

Comment: That would mean that Jon Skeet's votes would likely be attributable back to him as he would have such a large "weight".

Comment: How would the list of "endorsing" users be curated? Would we have to vote for whose votes carried more weight? Seems like a lot of work, and easily gameable.

Comment: @RobertLongson It's still a solvable problem though.  You could give X weight to the top y% of voters in the tag, such that there's always a large number of people with the same weight.

Comment: I altered the weight of this feature request by -1.

Comment: What problem does this solve?

Comment: Ok, maybe I should not have mentioned the names, and the example with the numbers was just an example. I only think that the votes is not the only way to measure the importance and utility of a question/answer. Also I was not giving any solution just asking a question.

Comment: @Eric when you make a feature request on meta, then you ARE making a suggestion... Anyway it doesnt change much. What if Jon Skeet 2.0 joins stack tomorrow... He's smarter, faster, clearer than Jon Skeet.... His votes should be weighted less because he hasnt beenon the site since its inception?

Comment: @Patrice that has happened already; Jon Skeet *is* Jon Skeet 2.0. And all future versions simultaneously.

Comment: @Glorfindel I know there cannot be a Jon Skeet 2.0. You can still get the point I'm making I hope :P

Comment: @Patrice With your comment I realize that I am completely wrong, I finally understood what are the problems that my suggestion can bring to stackoverflow and realize that I deserve all the downvotes, thank you so much, sincerelly.

Comment: @Eric no problem (if this wasn't sarcastic). But in any case don't fret the meta downvotes :) They don't cost rep BECAUSE it's not a big problem for them to be on a meta question (they indicate "I don't agree with your proposal", not "your question is bad")^^. Hopefully your coming to meta wasn't too rough :P

Comment: @Patrice Clearly it was not sarcasm, I am very grateful for your comment because it was respectful and gives me a logical reason, and maybe I do not express very well what I was thinking when I ask the question, and now I understood also that the downvotes are not a big deal, actually I only have an idea and think that could help me in some situations and try to comminicate it without thinking about it more deeply. Any way I mean my thanks.

Comment: @Eric sorry if i felt paranoid.. A lot of new meta users do end up extremely sarcastic :p. Glad I could help:) and honestly,keep bringing tbwse ideas up. As long as they make sense, and aren't duplicates, that's what meta is for :)

Comment: @BilltheLizard "What problem does this solve?" Higher statistical relevance of the displayed score maybe? However I doubt that and I'm against it.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to implement and no, it's not useful.

Comment: @Patrice The rep is trust. If Jon Skeet 2.0 joins tomorrow we could (if we wanted to) weigh his scoring contributions less because we do not trust him. We wouldn't even let him close vote (or downvote) right from the beginning. ;)

Answer (score 7):

It might be hard to believe, but Stack Overflow is

> intended to be a sort of representative democracy.

[(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)
That means *by definition* that everybody's vote has an equal weight, whether you're Jon Skeet or a total n00b in C#. Also, what is very useful to a beginner (e.g. [casting an `int` to an `enum`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482/cast-int-to-enum-in-c-sharp)) might not be useful to a veteran C# developer, because it is too simple for him/her.

Comment: Yes I understand that, I am not intending to remove the votes either. And the formula/computation of the value of the question can be as complex as you want, actually you are agree with me that are answer that have a lot of votes but little value.

Comment: *you are agree with me that are answer that have a lot of votes but little value.* yes, but this is not the way to solve it.